# How do I make an email event invitation show up in the iOS Mail and Calendar apps?

Tags: html-email, icalendar, schema.org, semantic-markup, json-ld

I added schema.org EventReservation markup as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/overview) to the purchase confirmation emails for my e-commerce ticketing site. The event now appears above the email in my desktop Gmail inbox:

[image: confirmation email with event]

However, when I open the email in the Mail app on my iPhone, I don't get an option to add this event to my calendar. The Calendar app says that I have no invitations in my Inbox. Is there a separate API or registration process to make my event invitations work with the iOS Mail and Calendar apps?

Comment: Yes, it's probably IMIP: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6047

Comment: I believe it simply scans the text of the email for dates - is the date in the text of the email?

Comment: Alternatively, you might like to add an ics file. That can trigger calendar functionality

Comment: The date is in the text of the email. Does it need to be in a certain format?